# Correct Way to update BIOS in dual boot machine

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, windows-8, bios

i would like to update my current BIOS version because my laptop is running rather hot in idle.
I have a DELL Inspiron 5547, single HDD, with Ubuntu 14.04 and Windows 8.1 installed (dual boot).
I went to Dell's website, downloaded official latest version of BIOS (A07) and the instructions say that it can be easily installed from Windows environment(.exe file + reboot).
If i do the update from Windows 8.1 is everything going to be ok with dual boot ? Will the update from the windows environment affect negatively, in terms of compatibility, linux drivers, grub etc ?
Or the whole idea is "unsafe" and may cause system crush ?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you successfully update the BIOS, result will be the same what ever way you choose, just follow the instructions. Don't worry and upgrade it from Windows. BIOS is loaded before operating system and it is an independent software.

About the compatibility, if you made any changes from default BIOS setup, you should make notes, so you can make the same changes after new BIOS is loaded. It is hard to say what could happen, usually BIOS upgrade will make unnoticeable changes, but in rare cases, some devices may change their behavior, in that case, you can always load previous version of BIOS, so make notes of your current version just to make sure.

Answer (score 0):

After updating my dual boot Dell Inspiron with Dell Windows tools, I lost the dual boot.
Going to the Bios Boot Sequence item, I found the only available boot option was Windows Boot Manager, so it was necessary add a boot option to regain access to the Grub2 boot.
To do this, staying with an UEFI boot, select Add Boot Options and get a dialog with a Filesystem List - select one of these and click the 3 dots beside File Name to get a list of files/directories.
Selecting any efi file in the file tree should give a valid boot.   It may be necessary to change the selected File System eg from FS0 to FS1 to find one.
In my case FS0/EFI/bootx64.efi was the correct choice.
After choosing this enter your name for this boot option and click to add it.
After the dialog closes configure the boot option sequence as required.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).